# Can I use Minecraft on a different computer than the one I bought it on?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I buy Minecraft on my laptop and I’m getting a new one at the end of the year can I get Minecraft on the new one I’m gonna get? I’ve seen people say this works but other people say it won't. I really want to play but I don't know if I’m going to have to buy it again and waste money?

Comment: Many people are confused about this but it's really simple. You bought a Minecraft account, not the game. The game is free to download from Minecraft.net and can be installed on any supported device. Once you install the game, log in using the account you purchased and you can continue playing like normal. However, the saves have to be copied over manually.

Answer (score 2):

MineCraft Mojang accounts can link to different computers by default, as long as you go to MineCraft's official website and log into your Mojang account, however you would probably not have your world saves and game files transfered over to the new computer by default, and instead would have to transfer them over yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Just download it on the other computer after logging in and make sure to save the files from your old Minecraft if you're planning on playing the same worlds.

The place to download the old files can usually be accessed by holding the windows key and pressing R, then typing in %appdata% the folder should be .minecraft